# opencv-access all pixels in tetragon

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a project in C++ using OpenCV.
I have coordinates of 4 vertices of tetragon stored in vector of Point2f.
I want to access all the pixels of this tetragon (to check what is the percentage of black pixels in its area).

Any ideas how to do it?

P.S. This tetragon is NOT a rectangle-that would be piece of cake.

**EDIT:**
To make things clear: I would like to iterate through every pixel inside tetragon (given by 4 vertices) to access its RGB value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of operation is akin to rasterizing, such as used in OpenGL to draw actual polygons, so FYI any information on rasterization can also help you. Using OpenGL to rasterize would be more efficient since graphics card have hardware just for that, but since your question is about OpenCV, let's use functions available in OpenCV.

First, we would call cvFillConvexPoly() or cvFillPoly() with your vertices to create a mask image, then we could call whatever function you are interested to use on your original image plus the mask. This way, when looping over the pixels, we only need to consider pixels whose corresponding mask values are not zero.

Comment: So you mean that I should create other image size exactly as my working image, and it all for example with white, then call cvFillPoly() to create black mask of tetragon. Then iterate through every pixel of image to find if it's black-and that's how I get every pixel inside my tetragon. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: OpenCV functions use masks with a black background and a white foreground, so we might as well follow that convention, but yes, your understanding is correct. But this is a very general procedure, whether we can do better depends what you intend on doing with all those pixels...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i understood your question correctly.

But to find area inside a tetragon, find the contour of tetragon and fill it with a different color, then find number of pixes with that color. That way you can get percentage.

Or you can use method of moments to find the area. Or try below links:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/58943
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/44428

If you want to access each pixels of tetragon, first you can find its contour and try "cvGetSeqElem" function. Try below links for some code:

http://osdir.com/ml/lib.opencv/2006-04/msg00044.html
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv/15170

Please tell me if misunderstood the question.

Comment: You have quite understood my question, I need to access every pixel inside tetragon.So the second pair of your links were a bit helpful. cvGetSeqElem would probably do the work, but how can I get a contour of my tetragon when I have only it's vertices?

Comment: Then first draw the polygon using OpenCV functions.  1)http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/core/basic_geometric_drawing/basic_geometric_drawing.html 2)http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/drawing_functions.html#polyline 3)http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly                Then as usual, find contour and use cvGetSeqElem function.

Comment: I've tried findContours function, but then I iterate only through a contour of the tetragon, not through pixels inside of it. Can you help me any further in this case?

Comment: It's in Python not C++, but I understand your idea. It's very similar to solution given by Samuel Audet. I was looking for something more sophisticated and more automatic but I think there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do some analytic geometry. you can consider your tetragon as a combination of two triangles. make a virtual line connecting two points they are not connected. Then, you can compute the points on a triangle using the equations of 3 lines surrounding it.

[image]

Comment: You misunderstood the question. I'm not looking for an area of my tetragon, I need to access each and every pixel inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can divide tetragon into two triangle and use triangle rasterization algorithm to solve the problem .the follow may help you [TriangleRasterization link](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/java/TriangleRasterization/TriangleRasterization.html)